# Add a new server to a farm, product key

Tags: 2013, server-farm, topology

I can't manage to find anything about this topic, but when you are about to add a new SharePoint server to a existing farm, must the server be installed with the same product key as the other servers in the farm? Or is it enough with a new product key for the same version of SharePoint?

Comment: The complete farm uses the same license model. So basically you should change the product key using the SharePoint Central Administration website.

Comment: So it wont matter if 2 servers in a farm runs with one enterprise product key and then i add a new server that runs with another enterprise product key?